# Python request working on postman but not in local machine

Tags: python, html, python-requests, postman

I am scraping using postman and I have located what data I need I just need it to work locally. Although it works in postman and in kaggle but not in local machine neither in colab. Here's the code for reference:
`

```
import requests

url = "https://apisae1.phdvasia.com/v1/product-hut-fe/localizations?order_type=C&disposition=C&limit=4"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'authority': 'apisae1.phdvasia.com',
  'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'client': '57950680-0208-4703-9e0b-c5a8cc45cf42',
  'lang': 'pt',
  'origin': 'https://www.pizzahut.com.br',
  'referer': 'https://www.pizzahut.com.br/',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/99.0.0.0',
  'Cookie': 'ak_bmsc=CA52AD92D65BE36761FAC7C181F253D0~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQxGvcF7RDj0SJAQAALPEpSRSGE7kXTAwqrRr6W7FKHAmAiIZLed4usMa8hURw56blJZSho5ANdgoKbhEiJCGu8lFXst2L2uWHVaoNXi3QZgkcGHgYmHvWNw94pK9aoh4zr9YvHaeMFRd5Xr01mSDpSfjtx7PwGydeGkLcRo+2PX6xlXM9UPSDal59DPOjkM0LclJgl0s3FOumelzJrL5f73VPNQBEmh9Ek+XInsBiO5z6x118opcFaDNoRGAW/8rnaYJgQNF/t7WgfddKr7VA6Dif7s6mA0kxiUYlXpjQLuaFvCNc++RO6+fqm0fPz8bz8BQPKg9OIjzDPSdXUrRMkpQhdmImyzNDv/v2MePK8H2BYZnjh1JK0Kuw; bm_sv=FBC11E925F19B3C0A6BA6708D42A3D3A~YAAQxGvcF8yxkESJAQAAFkxASRT933k/B3sEomiSPBAzN4AEskTpDt7ilDa1EZwRgSq0vPW3eeF1pcmF8mfeEzeUTd9M9cLkVh3FoENhHyaorUh9yPYxu06HHCdXltInBWkY5jXsNa18804DF6tVDieU0ZZd4cKm8o1AMB1luUPGsLPJewgPVQWNWMeKAz6PyZVo+qAcZPW67ACmEzr4J+SONmXPAiPlK0jn77bU8PEOWAukDLbeO6BzwGFm6a4ESjr3~1'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, allow_redirects=False)

print(response.text)
```

I tried changing user agent to random and even current version of browser I'm using and tried on other cloud services. It worked on kaggle but not on colaband local machine. PLs help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only header value you need is the client.

```
import requests
import json # only used for presentation

url = "https://apisae1.phdvasia.com/v1/product-hut-fe/localizations?order_type=C&disposition=C&limit=4"

headers = {
    'client': '57950680-0208-4703-9e0b-c5a8cc45cf42'
}

with requests.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
```

Without the client header (or an invalid client) you'll get HTTP 400

Comment: The above change gives a 403 error but only in VS code when I run it locally. It works in colab and in kaggle without any problem. What am I doing wrong here? @DarkKnight

Comment: @MohitSharma If you copy'n'paste the code in this answer and you get HTTP 403, that may be due to where you are in the world and some geographical constraint on the server side. Are you using a proxy or firewall? It works for me without exception (UK based)

Comment: Yes, it worked using a VPN. Thanks for ur help.